# Есть ли в русском языке слова, равные фразе?

Tags: семантика, недопустимая-метка, фразеология

Каких слов не хватает в русском языке? Имеются в виду слова, равные целой фразе.

Comment: Вопрос сформулирован некорректно. О метках вообще молчу. Модераторы, где вы?

Answer (score 1):

Времяпрепровождение. Все сложные слова можно считать фразой. Если бы вопрос был подробнее...

Answer (score 0):

Гм... Интересный вопрос. Например, я, переводя с японского, столкнулась с тем, что в японском языке гораздо больше форм одного и того же местоимения. Например, это касается "я": мужское, женское, нейтральное, вежливое, пренебрежительное, сверхгорделивое и т.д. - все это разные слова. И вот, передать оттенки этого местоимения в русском языке бывает очень трудно.
А вообще, вопрос, думаю, заслуживает не короткого ответа, а целой научной работы)))